# Phrase to say that something which happened twice already is likely to happen again

Tags: expressions

In French, there is the expression "jamais deux sans trois" (literally: "never twice without a third [time]").

We use it to express that something which has already happened twice is likely to happen again.

Can someone point to a good, idiomatic, English equivalent?

Comment: Not an expression. But there is a quote that goes something like: "_Do something once and it's an accident. Twice, a coincidence. If you do it a third time, then it's a natural law_". Google also points to what appears to be an adaptation by Paulo Coelho of your French expression: "_Everything that happens once can never happen again. But everything that happens twice will surely happen a third time_".

Comment: "Once is chance; twice, is coincidence, but three times is enemy action".

Comment: I heard it as "Once is happenstance, twice coincidence... three times: enemy action." EDIT: Heh, I never knew that, @Robusto. Shows the quote is in the wild disconnected of its origin, I guess.

Comment: [To lose one parent, Mr Worthing, may be regarded as a misfortune; to lose both looks like carelessness](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/27075.html) (Oscar Wilde, 1895). To lose **three** parents would be truly miraculous (FumbleFingers, 2012)

Comment: @coleopterist arrgh, I was sure someone would mention paulo coelho :)

Comment: One beer's plenty, two's too many and three ain't half enough.  No wait...

Comment: Might be related to Lionel Richie's "You're once twice
 Three times a lady" (Three Times A Lady)

Comment: Japanese has something like this too: "一回あれば二回もある” (ikkai areba, nikai mo aru). If something happens once, it often happens twice. Or: things usually don't happen in isolation. "Where there is smoke, there is fire".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not superstitous but I have often heard more superstious people say:

> Bad things come in threes!

so that might be something.  This is most often said after occurence two in anticipation of occurence three.

I would have thought "jamais deux sans trois" would be more like "never twice without a third [time]", and I guess I would suggest that while not an idiomatic expression there is nothing wrong per se with a basic translation as a phrase.

> If it happened twice, it will probably happen again!

Comment: Yes, that's what the French means, my original translation was a pointless attempt at brevity.

Comment: They also say good things come in threes.

Answer (score 6):

I've already heard those in English :

- [everything comes in threes](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everything%20comes%20in%20threes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
- [never two without three](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never%20two%20without%20three&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
- [good things come in threes](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good%20things%20come%20in%20threes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
- [bad things come in threes](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bad%20things%20come%20in%20threes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 4):

There is a classic [Wizard of Id](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Id) cartoon in which the Little King throws a servant in the dungeon for 20 years for being late to work. The King's advisor whispers that this was the first lateness in 20 years of service. The King replies

> *Can't you see the pattern forming?*

Answer (score 3):

One could always say it is **a safe bet** or **a good bet** that 'whatever' will happen again. ([reference](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/Something-that-is-certain-or-likely-to-happen))

Or, depending on the situation, one could always say ***history repeats itself*** to convey that a situation is happening again, or *is likely to happen again*. ([reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/History+repeats+itself))

(I personally prefer the second option over the first one)

Answer (score 3):

A more generalized version would be *"When it rains, it pours"*, which I was taught back in French class was equivalent at least in usage if not literal meaning to *"jamais deux sans trois"*.

Comment: Actually, I believe this was originally "It never rains without it pours." A number of later versions exist with other words substituted for "without."  Morton's salt famously played upon this well-known adage in their advertisement for a new type of coated (non-clumping) salt : "When it rains, it pours."