# What does "what happens twice, happens thrice" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the old phrase "What happens twice, happens thrice" mean?

Comment: Relevant:[Phrase to say something that happened twice is already likely to happen again.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83614/phrase-to-say-that-something-which-happened-twice-already-is-likely-to-happen-ag)

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, that comes from a quote by Paulo Coelho. The full proverb is:

> "Everything that happens once can never happen twice. But everything that happens twice will surely happen a third time."

My interpretation:

***Something that happens once*** is always something that happens once, by literal interpretation and definition; if it happens more than once, it isn't something that happens once.

***Something that happens twice*** is referring to something that is not a one-time occurrence and therefore is not a chance occurrence. Because it's not a one-time occurrence, the proverb implies it to be a recurring one.

This proverb can be applied to endless situations and interpretations; it all depends on the mind that reads it. One example I've seen used more than others:

> Girl and Boy are dating. Girl cheats on Boy with Man. Boy finds out and breaks up with Girl. Man starts dating Girl because she has only ever cheated once; there is no reason to think she will again. Girl then cheats on Man with Boy. Man finds out and breaks up with Girl. Boy will not date Girl because now she has cheated twice and most likely will cheat again.

Comment: Nit-pick - I think 'recurring' might be a better word choice than 'recursive'.

Comment: I think they are interchangeable, although recursive is more prevalent in a technical/computer sense. But, I have no problem changing it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Technically speaking, he wrote: [*Tudo que acontece uma vez poderá nunca mais acontecer, mas tudo o que acontece duas vezes, certamente acontecerá uma terceira.*](https://pensador.uol.com.br/frases_do_livro_o_alquimista/) :)